# Registering iOS devices for use with Amazon SNS (APNS) through Amazon Anonymous TVM

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Similar questions appear several times on StackOverflow with no solution for Amazon SNS.

[This documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-send-devicetoken.html) states that registering devices for Amazon SNS (APNS) can be completed through an Anonymous Token Vending Machine. [This documentation](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx371Y7CA0QJ95X/Simplifying-Token-Vending-Machine-Deployment-with-AWS-CloudFormation) provides a template for deployment, which I have used, then [this code sample](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/S3_SimpleDB_SNS_SQS_DemoTVM) specifies an iOS client which demonstrates its use. However, not in the template configuration source or the iOS client example do I see how the TVM is linked to the SNS application to create device entries (referred to as endpoints). Any ideas where this occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out reference is linked client-side. The solution was as follows:

```
Include:

AWSRuntime.framework
AWSSecurityTokenService.framework
AWSSNS.framework


#define SNS_PLATFORM_APPLICATION_ARN @"Insert ARN here"
#define TOKEN_VENDING_MACHINE_URL @"Insert vending machine url, found in output tab"
#define USE_SSL 1

#pragma mark - Amazon TVM


+ (void)initSNS
{
    AmazonCredentials *credentials = [AmazonKeyChainWrapper getCredentialsFromKeyChain];

    sns = [[AmazonSNSClient alloc] initWithCredentials:credentials];
    sns.endpoint = [AmazonEndpoints snsEndpoint:US_WEST_2];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
}

+ (AmazonTVMClient *)tvm
{
    if (tvm == nil) {
        tvm = [[AmazonTVMClient alloc] initWithEndpoint:TOKEN_VENDING_MACHINE_URL useSSL:USE_SSL];
    }

    return tvm;
}

+ (bool)hasCredentials
{
    return ![TOKEN_VENDING_MACHINE_URL isEqualToString:@"CHANGE ME"];
}

+ (Response *)validateCredentials
{
    Response *ableToGetToken = [[Response alloc] initWithCode:200 andMessage:@"OK"];

    if ([AmazonKeyChainWrapper areCredentialsExpired]) {

        @synchronized(self)
        {
            if ([AmazonKeyChainWrapper areCredentialsExpired]) {

                ableToGetToken = [[self tvm] anonymousRegister];

                if ( [ableToGetToken wasSuccessful])
                {
                    ableToGetToken = [[self tvm] getToken];

                    if ( [ableToGetToken wasSuccessful])
                    {
                        [AppDelegate initSNS];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        [AppDelegate initSNS];
    }

    return ableToGetToken;
}

#pragma mark - Push Notification

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", userInfo];
    NSLog( @"%@", msg );

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message Received" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", msg]delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}


-(NSString*)deviceTokenAsString:(NSData*)deviceTokenData
{
    NSString *rawDeviceTring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", deviceTokenData];
    NSString *noSpaces = [rawDeviceTring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSString *tmp1 = [noSpaces stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];

    return [tmp1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    NSLog( @"Submit the device token [%@] to SNS to receive notifications.", deviceToken );
    SNSCreatePlatformEndpointRequest *platformEndpointRequest = [SNSCreatePlatformEndpointRequest new];
    platformEndpointRequest.customUserData =  @"Here's the custom data for the user.";
    platformEndpointRequest.token = [self deviceTokenAsString:deviceToken];
    platformEndpointRequest.platformApplicationArn = SNS_PLATFORM_APPLICATION_ARN;

    [sns createPlatformEndpoint:platformEndpointRequest];
}
```